# refactoring code with conditional return

Tags: python

I have this code on my project in the begining of multiple functions.

```
try: 
    user = get_user(user_id) 
except LockedException: 
    logger.warn('op=healthcheck, msg="user is locked"') 
    return HttpResponseServerError(jsonMessage('user=%(user)s is locked' % {'user': user_id})) 
except UserFreeException: 
    logger.warn('op=user, msg="user is free"') 
    return HttpResponseNotFound(jsonMessage('user is free user=%(user)s' % {'user': user_id})) 
except User.DoesNotExist: 
    logger.warn('op=healthcheck, msg="user doesn\'t exist"') 
    return HttpResponseNotFound(jsonMessage('invalid user=%(user)s' % {'user': user_id})) 
except Exception, e: 
    logger.error('op=healthcheck, msg="unknown error", msg="%(exception)s"', 
                 {'exception': e.message}) 
    return HttpResponseServerError(jsonMessage(e.message))
```

Any hints on how can I refactor it so I don't need to reuse it everywhere?
The best I could come would be to create a function that throws a single exception in case of a problem, and this exception contains a "http_response" field, so I'd do something like:

```
try:
    user = get_user(user_id)
except MyGenericException, e:
    return e.http_response
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a decorator that executes this logic before the function body of the decorated functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated with @steveha's suggestion

What about having it in a function:

```
def safe_get_user(user_id):
    user = error_response = None
    try: 
        user = get_user(user_id) 
    except LockedException: 
        logger.warn('op=healthcheck, msg="user is locked"') 
        error_response = HttpResponseServerError(jsonMessage('user=%(user)s is locked' % {'user': user_id})) 
    except UserFreeException: 
        logger.warn('op=user, msg="user is free"') 
        error_response = HttpResponseNotFound(jsonMessage('user is free user=%(user)s' % {'user': user_id})) 
    except User.DoesNotExist: 
        logger.warn('op=healthcheck, msg="user doesn\'t exist"') 
        error_response = HttpResponseNotFound(jsonMessage('invalid user=%(user)s' % {'user': user_id})) 
    except Exception, e: 
        logger.error('op=healthcheck, msg="unknown error", msg="%(exception)s"', 
             {'exception': e.message}) 
        error_response = HttpResponseServerError(jsonMessage(e.message))
    return user, error_response
```

And then, everywhere you want to execute it:

```
user, error_response = safe_get_user(user_id)
if error_response is not None:
    return error_response
```

Comment: Instead of checking the type, I prefer to return a tuple of results: `(good_result, error_result)`  On success, return `None` as the `error_result` part; on failure, return `None` as the `good_result` part.  Then it is `if error_result: return error_result`

Comment: I like it, thanks @steveha! It's clearer and cleaner :)